# GetProto method throws NotImplementedException in protobuf-net v2 beta r431

Tags: protobuf-net

The entity I am working with is rather simple:

```
[ProtoContract]
class FlatEntity
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string Value;
}
```

When I run this line of code:

```
var proto = Serializer.GetProto<FlatEntity>();
```

I get the following exception:

**Message**: "The method or operation is not implemented."

**StackTrace**:

at ProtoBuf.Serializer.GetProtoT in C:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Serializer.cs:line 39
   at ConsoleApplication2.Program.SerializationBenchmark() in C:\Users\eladm.SOLUTO\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\Program.cs:line 48
   at ConsoleApplication2.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\eladm.SOLUTO\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\Program.cs:line 26

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Thanks,
Elad

Comment: Yes. That remains an outstanding work-item on the v2 plan. It'll work in v1, but the v1 code is not *at all* compatible with the v2 model.

Comment: I really need this feature too. Trying to write my own but having problems with it.

Comment: This is now available in v2 using r580 and higher, as Marc Gravell reports [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9892910/protobuf-net-getprototype-method-throws-a-not-implemented-exception)