# Protobuf.net GetProto<Type>() method throws a not implemented exception

Tags: protobuf-net

I have a .net application that serializes using protobuf, and I wanted to create a python client that can communicate with it. Since my object graph is quite complex (and I am <strike>lazy</strike> busy) I wanted to quickly generate the .proto files directly from the C# classes like this:

```
    string proto = Serializer.GetProto<YourType>();
```

Unfortunately this method is throwing a not implemented exception for me :'(

I am using [the Dec 11 version](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/downloads/list)

Has this feature been dropped? Is there a newer version I should be using? Or failing that, can anyone recommend an older version of it that I can temporarily use to create the .proto files?

Thanks <333

Comment: this was re-implemented in v2 quite a while ago now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was re-implemented quite a while ago now; it is certainly available in r580 and higher.

<s>Not dropped... Just not part of the core baseline that I *absolutely needed* to release v2. It is very much on my list to re-implement, but the type-model changed significantly between v1 and v2, necessitating a full rewrite of this code.</s>

V1 is still available for download and should work in most reasonable cases. However, note that protobuf-net allows for more than the core specification - things like inheritance/generics don't have any meaning in .proto, and teen things like System.DateTime/System.Decimal need special handling. Basically, GetProto may get you *most* of the way there!

Comment: Great, thanks!!! We are just trying out Protobuf in my company, and I can see lots of instances where GetProto would be useful. My team develop primarily in c#, but wish to provide service access to other developers using Python or C++, and I don't want to have to spend hours reverse engineering all our object models. Great library though, it has already saved me loads of time <3 (10 minutes from the initial google search for the download to having my zeroMQ prototype serializing a complex object graph)

Comment: Same here - we need to provide cross-platform serialization, with C# object models in the lead. It would be ideal if we could take a TypeModel populated from the C# OM and distribute it to Java and Python people. The other way around - starting from a .proto and generating the C# and non-C# OM's - would be less than ideal.

Comment: Another vote to get this implemented. C# message definitions in "the lead" with C++ or Python interpretations via protobuf.net-specified patterns for inheritance, DateTime, etc. would be lovely.

Comment: @SebastianGood the patterns used by protobuf-net for DateTime etc are all in bcl.proto; the patterns used for inheritance is clearly explained in the output from GetProto (which was re-implemented some time ago now (updating answer)).

Comment: Fantastic! I was led astray as the latest version NuGet advertises is r480. I will download and build from source to get the new functionality

Comment: @SebastianGood actually, NuGet has r580 if you ask for it specifically: `PM> Install-Package protobuf-net -Version 2.0.0.580`